# using LINQ to extract sections out of a string array into a new collection

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, collections

I have a string array in this format (each line is a slot in the array):

IT1
PID
Ref
Ref
REF
IT1
PID
REF
IT1
PID
Ref
REF
...

I want to extract each IT1 through the last REF into a new array using LINQ. The new result would be an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`.

Using the above string slot array example, the new IEnumerable collection should have 3 `IEnumerable<string>` in it.

For example:

class 1
IT1
PID
Ref
Ref
REF
end class 1

class 2
IT1
PID
REF
end class 2

class 3
IT1
PID
Ref
REF
end class 3
...

Notice some sections of the array have 1 REF, some 2 REF and some 3 REF.

How can I use LINQ to extract each section from IT1 through the last REF into a new collection of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`?

Psudo code...

```
var result = arrayData.Select(s => s.StartsWith("IT1")
.GroupBy(...)
.Select(result => new {IT1 through last ref goes here})
.ToArray();
```

Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can partition the array using `GroupBy` and some temporary state like this:

```
var counter = 0;
var arrays = input.GroupBy(s => counter += s == "IT1" ? 1 : 0)
                  .Select(g => g.ToArray())
                  .ToArray();
```

This will give you an array of arrays; each sub-array will start with an `"IT1"` element and end with whatever your input had before the next `"IT1"`. If your data is valid, that will be a `"REF"`. If the data is invalid, you need to specify what should happen in this case.

I 'm not so sure how you expect these arrays to be converted into anonymous objects though. Anonymous objects might have an unknown type name, but they are still very strongly typed: you cannot dynamically decide the amount, names, and types of their members.

Comment: Thanks @Jon this is working. You are correct, I could not get a class or anonymous type so I edited my original question to ask about getting an IEnumerable of IEnumerable string. I do need to stop the grouping when I arrive at a slot in the array with CCT in the array slot. How can I adjust your code to stop and not include CCT or anything past CCT in the array? The CCT and items past it in the array are not needed and can be seen as invalid. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could change @Jon code from `g => g.ToArray()` to `g => g.TakeWhile(s => s != "CCT").ToArray()`

Comment: @Frekster: Wasp's comment is just fine for that.

Comment: Thanks Jon and Wasp - it works! Here is my final code for anyone else interested. Instead of testing for == I used .StartsWith but others can adjust the test as necessary to be whatever test on a string that is required. Jon I am going to mark your solution as the answer.  var arrays = input.GroupBy(s => counter += s.StartsWith("IT1") ? 1 : 0)
            .Select(g => g.TakeWhile(s => !s.StartsWith("CCT")).ToArray()) // CCT is where we stop grabbing data 
            .ToArray()
            .Skip(1) // skip first slot in array not an IT1
.ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Partitian(IEnumerable<string> source)
{
    List<string> buffer = new List<string>();
    int? lastRef = null;

    int position = 0;
    foreach (string s in source)
    {
        if (s == "REF")
            lastRef = position;
        else if (s == "IT1" && lastRef.HasValue)
        {
            yield return buffer.Take(lastRef.Value + 1);
            buffer.Clear();
            position = 0;
            lastRef = null;
        }
        buffer.Add(s);

        position++;
    }

    if (buffer.Any() && lastRef.HasValue)
        yield return buffer;
}
```